# Facebook groupsApi & group_access_member_info problem

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a public Facebook group and I am trying to get the posts and the author of the post via graphql. My app has been approved by Facebook and I have installed it in my group. Also, it is live
[image]

My problem is that when I send a get request I can see only my name and ID and I can't see other names. I can see their posts just fine but without their info.

[image]

All the users inside my group have given me access to their information. For example this user
[image]

Also I notice that if i send a get request to this url [image]

I am getting back a list only with my user. I expected to get a list with all the users who allow me access to their data.

All the request that i send is from my user who is also admin in the group

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're hitting a GraphQL API. GraphQL requests are POSTs that include a *query* string and *variables*.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I didn't understand. Can you elaborate more, please? Btw I am hitting Facebook Graphql API from the facebook url (https://developers.facebook.com)

Comment: Those GETs you are doing are not GraphQL - please point at the API docs page for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MichelFloyd not everything within the API is using POST, and for querying a feed, GET is the correct method to use. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#read

Comment: @MichelFloyd I am trying to get the posts of the group based on this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/guides#getting-group-posts. I have successfully gotten the posts but without the `from` field. What I am trying to do is to get the posts with the `from` field. From the docs you can see that in order to get the `from` the user has to grant the `groups_access_member_info permission`. I have done all of this but still, the response that I am getting back has no `from` field.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I am hitting the API with the admin user of the group

Comment: Just FYI - the api you pointed to is *not* GraphQL, it just a REST API. (Hence the GETs instead of POSTs).